# how to log the file requested via express.static

Tags: node.js, express

here is my code

```
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
var port=8181;
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.listen(port);
```

it is serving static file  properly

I want to log when a  file with an extension .xls is being requested

how can i achieve it ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) core module gives you the tools to deal with this. So, just put this logic in a middleware *before your static middleware*, like:

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");

var app = express();
var port = 8181;

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var filename = path.basename(req.url);
    var extension = path.extname(filename);
    if (extension === '.css')
        console.log("The file " + filename + " was requested.");
    next();
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.listen(port);
```

Comment: @ahhmar note that order matters, if you put the static middleware above the logger middleware, a response will be sent and the logger would not be called

Comment: if I don't add the check for extension === '.css', all the requested files are listed (quite useful!), the first one being "". Is that the request for "/" itself?

Answer (score 6):

You want to log what *serve-static* (`express.static`) gives in response. There're several ways to do this.

#### <sup>Method Ⅰ</sup> A middleware for manual checks.

You may put (`app.use`) a middleware that logs a request if it's for `express.static`, before `express.static`. [*Rodrigo Medeiros*' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29371929/4510033) does this. But this way, **you have to rewrite the code for checks when the options for the *serve-static* middleware changes**, which might be a maintaining issue.

#### <sup>Method Ⅱ</sup> Hooking into `express.static`; leaking info out of it.

Well, `express.static` knows what files it gives best. It just, unfortunately, does not let us know and log it. But there's a hack for this: [the `setHeaders` option](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#setHeaders), which is a callback function supposedly used to set custom response headers. It's called when `express.static` makes a response and gets enough information to log what you want to.

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const asset_dir_path = "assets/";

app.use(express.static(asset_dir_path, {
    index: false,
    setHeaders: (response, file_path, file_stats) => {
        // This function is called when “serve-static” makes a response.
        // Note that `file_path` is an absolute path.

        // Logging work
        const relative_path = path.join(asset_dir_path, path.relative(asset_dir_path, file_path));
        console.info(`@${Date.now()}`, "GAVE\t\t", relative_path);
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 4):

Just do

```
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
var port=8181;

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // check for .xls extension
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    next();
}, express.static(__dirname));

app.listen(port);
```

Comment: this doesn't let you check the status code of the response, which is half of the point