# How to log all outgoing requests on NodeJS/Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm doing a research on logging outgoing requests on a NodeJS/Express app.

What ways are possible to log all requests made from the web app?

With this I mean all `fetch()` requests, but also all `<img src="">`, `<script src="">` calls etc. 
I know of solutions like `new relic`and `bluetriangle`, which actually log those requests. I'd like to rebuild this behaviour and log everything from a express app perspective (if possible)

I've seen npm packages like `morgan` & `winston`, but those only seem to log requests made to the express app.

Does anyone have any ideas or great docs for logging all requests.

Comment: Shouldn't the title refer to "_incoming_ requests" then?

Comment: I don't think so. I'd like to log all requests made to external sources, originating from my web app. If I'm correct those are outgoing requests.

Comment: Requesting a static resource is technically no different then sending a request to a custom endpoint. Both are incoming HTTP requests served by the Node/Express server.

Comment: You can always create your own middleware: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368879/how-to-log-the-file-requested-via-express-static

Comment: Yes, but that will only track the internal requests to the node server. Not everything else.

Comment: It’s not clear what other requests are possible. Is the web app sending requests to 3rd parties?

Answer (score 0):

You can't log requests done client side (`<img src="">, <script src="">`) automatically because these requests are made by the client not by your server.

You'll need to manually log these by sending them to your server on client events but i don't know why do you need these logs.

Comment: The web app is a part of a larger structure. Logging al requests for all users would mean, that it's possible to see the impact of certain external files on loading times. 
Would it be possible to intercept the client side requests with a service worker?